# How do I wait for foreach in NodeJS before returning the populated array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In the following code I am using nano package of NodeJS to use CouchDB. I am fetching some records and populating the array before returning it. But instead the function is returning undefined value. How do I wait for foreach to finish first.

Here's the code Snippet

```
function getVoters(){
var voters = new Array();
const db = getConnection();

db.view('typeDesignDoc','voterView',function(err, body){    
    if(!err){
        body.rows.forEach(function(doc){
            voters.push(doc);
            console.log(voters);
        });
        return voters;
    }
    else
        console.log(err);
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it using the callback or promise.

```js
function getVoters(cb) {
 var voters = new Array();
 const db = getConnection();

 db.view('typeDesignDoc', 'voterView', function (err, body) {
  if (!err) {
   body.rows.forEach(function (doc) {
    voters.push(doc);
    console.log(voters);
   });
   cb(null,voters);
  }
  else
   cb(err);
 });
}
```

Using Promise

```js
let Promise = require('bluebird');

function getVoters(cb) {
 var voters = new Array();
 const db = getConnection();
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.view('typeDesignDoc', 'voterView', function (err, body) {
   if (!err) {
    body.rows.forEach(function (doc) {
     voters.push(doc);
     console.log(voters);
    });
    return resolve(voters);
   }
   else
    return reject(err);
  });
 });
}
```

OR

use promisifieded driver for couch DB [couchdb-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchdb-promises)

OR use the promisifyAll method to promisify all the methods of your existing driver module. However, there is a restriction on promisifying the fuction

Comment: In first method, using callbacks, the cb is getting executed before foreach completes.

Comment: you are passing the callback function when calling getVoters?

Comment: you need to call it like getVoters((err, result) => {}); are you doing the same cuz I don't see how cb will execute before forEach

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await provided `db.view` returns a promise and re-factor your code to look like:

```
const getVoters = async () => {
    const db = getConnection();

    try {
        const body = await db.view('typeDesignDoc','voterView');
        const voters = body.rows.map(doc => doc);
        return voters;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

// Call your function later like:
const voters = (async () => {
    return await getVoters();
})();
```